# Need to replace all the <asp:DropDownList> with telerik equivalent

Tags: webforms, telerik, rad-controls

I need to replace all the `<asp:DropDownList>` with telerik's equivalent control
what is the effective way to achieve this?

thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be their combobox, friend. Check the demos here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Yes the Combobox!! I was wondering whether I have to re write a lot of code. I will take a look at it. Thanks!!

Comment: depending on what kind of code interaction you have, you won't 'have' to re-factor much code at all ...but the telerik version has some nice additional features you may want to take advantage of, definitely look at AutomaticLoadOnDemand when not using a small finite number of options

Answer (score 1):

The Q1'13 version has introduced the RadDropDownList control.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

I think it's the most effective way to resolve your problem!